# Return value from subset of rows

Tags: r

Consider the following data

```
df <- data.frame(a=c("a","a","b"), b=c(3,4,5), c=c(4,5,6))
df$a <- as.factor(df$a)
```

The command below returns the values of "b" when a="a".

```
df[df$a=="a","b"]
[1] 3 4
```

How can I return the nth value of this column? I tried the following to return the first value but which just returns the same.

```
df[df$a=="a","b",1]
[1] 3 4
```

The idea is to eventually transpose this concept to multiple dataframes in a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df[df$a == "a", "b"]

#[1] 3 4
```

This is a vector.

```
is.vector(df[df$a == "a", "b"])
#[1] TRUE
```

Now to get the nth element of the vector you can index it using the general indexing technique

```
df[df$a == "a", "b"][1]
#[1] 3
```

Or

```
df[df$a == "a", "b"][2]
#[1] 4
```

which gives you the particular value you need.

Answer (score 1):

Return the second value

```
df[which(df$a=="a"),"b"][2]
[1] 4
```

Answer (score 1):

This is fundamentally a question about subsetting data.frames in r. Basically what you do is:

```
df[rows, columns]
```

rows and columns can be logical, and integer with the row/column index, the names. if you do not specify the rows and/or columns all of them will be returned.

```
df[, columns] #returns all rows and a subset of columns
df[rows, ] #returns all columns and a subset of rows
df[, ] # returns all rows and columns
```

`df[df$a=="a","b"]` returns all rows where column "a" is equal to the letter "a" (`df$a=="a"` returns `1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE`)and then selects only column "b" which returns the vector `[1] 3 4`.

You can then subset this vector further by adding `[n]`:

```
df[df$a=="a", "b"][1]
[1] 3
df[df$a=="a", "b"][2]
[1] 4
```

Answer (score 1):

`dplyr` option:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
   filter(a == "a") %>%    # filter where column a = "a"
   slice(2)  %>%           # get 2nd row
   pull(b)                 # get value as a vector instead of tibble

# [1] 4
```

Or

```
df %>% 
  filter(a == "a") %>%    # filter where column a = "a"
  pull(b) %>%             # get column as a vector instead of tibble
  nth(2)                  # get 2nd value

# [1] 4
```

Comment: `collect()` doesn't work for me. Maybe `df %>% filter(a == "a") %>% .$b %>% nth(1)` ?

Answer (score 0):

use ***dplyr.***

```
nth(df[df$a == "a", "b"],1)
```

here 1 is first value in the vector.